# how to configure the scrollbar within kivy AccordionItem?

Tags: kivy, accordion

I want to configure the scrollbar within the AccordionItem. The following code does not seem to have any effect. How could this be done?

```
AccordionItem:
    bar_width: '15dp'
    bar_color: 0.14,0.35,0.44,1
    bar_inactive_color: 0.14,0.35,0.44,1
    bar_margin: '2dp'
    id: '$acc_id'
    title: '$acc_title'
    font_name: 'Roboto'
    image: '$acc_image'
    text: '$acc_text'
    min_space: 30
    RstDocument:
        id: rstcontent
        background_color: 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1
        text: '$rstcontent'
            ''')
```

Comment: which scrollbar do you mean? the one associated with the RstDocument? If so why should the Accordian have any influence on that? Which part of the code specifically do you think is not working?

Comment: hmm, good question. This points me to the real focus area. It is the scrollbar in the RstDocument. So that's where I probably should put the bar_width ... bar_margin specifications?

Comment: probably, or add a slider to the restdocument which takes over the scrolling